# How to change select-by-word behavior in Gnome Terminal 3.14.2

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, dconf

I tried the following:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:{my-profile-id}/word-char-exceptions '@ms "-,.;/?%&#_=+@~·:"'
```

but all I get is

```
error: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

How do I get to the bottom of this? There is nothing in system log viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was removed in GNOME 3.14 and will be back with GNOME 3.16. The latter, I can confirm, I use GNOME 3.16

```
% dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:4d4a684a-7388-40db-adf1-6ec6b6f9043d/
foreground-color
visible-name
palette
word-char-exceptions
custom-command
default-size-columns
default-size-rows
use-system-font
use-custom-command
use-custom-default-size
use-theme-colors
use-transparent-background
font
scrollback-unlimited
bold-color-same-as-fg
bold-color
background-color
background-transparency-percent
scrollbar-policy
```

<sub>[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1401207)</sub>

Comment: on gnome terminal 3.36 and it no longer works :(